# What do I do to remove a post and not have a 404 show up?

Tags: wordpress, tags, duplicate-data

I want to delete several old posts from my site.  How do I do that without creating 404 errors if the post is already indexed in Google?

I have 4 wordpress sites. Does Google penalize me for moving posts from one site to another or duplicating them?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a plugin to redirect users from the old URL to the new URL, which Google should eventually catch up with. I would recommend something like [Redirection (link).](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove from Google the links using webmasters tools (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools)

1 - On the Webmaster Tools home page, click the site you want.
2 - On the Dashboard, click Optimization on the left-hand menu.
3 - Click Remove URLs.
4 - Click New removal request.
5 - Type the URL of the page you want removed from search results (not the Google search results URL or cached page URL), and then click Continue. The URL is case-sensitive—use exactly the same characters and capitalization that the site uses.
6 - Click Yes, remove this page.
7 - Click Submit Request.